# How to use a file created by a jar file in a docker container as volume

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I am running a jar file inside a docker container. There are some rest services which I can access through the container. One of the resource creates a json file of java objects. I want this file to be used as a volume so if the container is deleted and recreated again the previously stored data which was in this file is returned.

Answer (score 0):

A convenient way to do it is by using `docker-compose`.

create a `docker-compose.yml` along these lines.

```
app:
 build: .
 ports:
  - "8000:80"
 volumes:
  - "./your-computer:/container/path:rw"
```

`volumes` maps the `your-computer` directory on the host to `/container/path` in the container, with read and write access.

`build` builds it from the `Dockerfile` in the parent directory

`ports` maps the external port 8000 to the internal port 80

To run, just use: `docker-compose up -d`